# Algebraic Hecke characters and CM elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, and $E$ an elliptic curve over a number field $F$ with complex multiplicatio by the ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$. Then the main theorem of complex multplication says that there exists an algebraic Hecke character of $F$ with values in $K^\times$ satisfying certain properties.

Is the converse true? Namely, given such an algebraic Hecke character, can we associate to it a CM elliptic curve?

Comment: You need that $\psi$ is non-trivial, $L(s,\psi)$ has rational coefficients and $\psi((p)) = \pm p$, this way it is the Mellin transform of a weight $2$ cusp eigenform whose coefficients are the L-function of an ellliptic curve obtained by quotienting $J_0(N)$, it is obvious that this elliptic curve has CM but I don't know why.

Comment: CM = reducible Galois module I think.